# c# Unity 3D - 1000 cube instantiation script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Why does the following script make Unity run very slowly and unusable?

```
public Transform brick;
public int gridWidth=10;
public int gridDepth=10;
public int gridHeight=10;
void Start() {
    for (int y = 0; y < gridHeight; y=y+2) 
    {
        for (int z = 0; z < gridDepth; z=z+2) 
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < gridWidth; x=x+2) 
            {
                Instantiate (brick, new Vector3 (x, y, z), Quaternion.identity);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the transform I place a prefab that is basically a rigid body cube.

If I remove the For-Loop containing the z int, it runs OK (so a 10x10 grid / 100 cubes is fine).  However, with the z int loop in place it breaks ( a 10x10x10 grid / 1000 cubes)

How could I get this to actually work sensibly without making Unity unusable?

Comment: instantiaring 1000 game objects is going to slow things down noticably, question is is it only slow for a second (instantiate) or for anytime aftwerwards? (too much to render)

Comment: Slow all the time.  I noticed that I hadn't recompiled my code after though which in Unity meant a 100x100x100 grid had stuck, however, after recompiling a 10x10x10 grid works fine.  50x50x50 is slow at first but OK after....75x75x75 brings everything to a grinding halt.  At 75x75x75 I've turned rendering off and its still slow....so assuming it could be something else but that said, 75x75x75 is 400,000+ objects, so I guess it would be slow!

Comment: keep in mind that it runs good/bad *on your particular system* which may be significantly faster/slower than the (minimum requirements) system other users will run your game on.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best solution would be to use Oclussion Culling. It's a system that "doesnt render" the objects that are not visible by the active cam.

Here is the Unity information about it.

[Oclussion Culling at Unity Manual (PRO ONLY)](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/OcclusionCulling.html)

This function, however, is only available for the Unity Pro users, and if you have the Free version you should look for a custom Oclussion Culling script like this one:

[Oclussion Culling](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/improvised-run-time-occlusion-culling-in-any-version-of-unity-via-frustum-culling.150377/)

Keep in mind that this is only a script I found online, and there might be much better ones out there. Anyways, in words of the creator of that script:

> In my test scene the script delivered a >80% reduction in draw calls/tris/verts and >85% faster renderer loop, at the cost of a 12% reduction of frame rate (from 75 to 66 FPS). While this is great for scenes that are being bogged down by draw calls, I'm interested in any feedback that can reduce the script's overhead to make it suitable for general use.

It may be worth to check it out.

Comment: Unity Pro's occlusion culling is meant to be precomputed (in the "bake" step). It won't work for a procedurally generated scene.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you may remove rigid body from prefab; leave it only with box collider and make it [static](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/StaticObjects.html). First of all this will allow Unity to effectively [batch draw calls](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/DrawCallBatching.html). And PhysX will be able to utilize [broad phase](https://developer.nvidia.com/sites/default/files/akamai/physx/Docs/Broadphase.html) and improve performance of collision detection.

Comment: afaik batch drawing is only available in Unity Pro

Comment: @LearnCocos2D, yep, that's true

Answer (score 0):

I might be looking too far into this example, but it *seems* like you're trying to emulate "block-ily" rendered voxels.

While for a *very* simple example cubes might work, there is a definite limit to how many you can instantiate, render, and have the physics system keep track off, even with culling.

You should use an approach to rendering voxels that generates singular meshes of a areas of a predefined size (often called "chunks"). This allows for a single draw call for each material, inherent culling that's faster than anything that could automatically be generated (since it's a "free" side-effect of generating the mesh), a removal of the overhead of multiple colliders, and *much much more*.

It's a task that *sounds* much more daunting than it actually is. There are [numerous tutorials](http://unitycoder.com/blog/2012/10/18/voxel-resources-engines-for-unity/) that will go over what you need. I also found [these](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/coredev-creating-voxelised-worlds-like-minecraft.192954/) [three](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/tutorial-procedural-meshes-and-voxel-terrain-c.198651/) [sources](http://www.blockstory.net/node/56) to be particularly well written.

I personally wouldn't recommend trying to get your current approach to work using occlusion culling and batching alone, since it's still an extremely inefficient approach to this. Also note that Unity Pro's occlusion culling is designed to be pre-computated, so it won't work in your case.

Answer (score 0):

SPAWN A CUBE OF CUBES .

```
public Transform cubePrefab;

public int rows,columns,depth;
public float padding;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    for(int i =0; i < depth; i ++) {
        for(int j=0;j< columns;j++){
            for(int k=0; k < rows;k++){
                Vector3 pos = new Vector3(k * padding,j * padding,i * padding);
                //print(pos);
                Transform foo = (Transform) Instantiate(cubePrefab,pos,Quaternion.identity);
            }
        }
    }
}
```